# Unable to boot, because initial ram disk for kernel cannot be created

Tags: 14.04, kernel, mount, disk-usage, boot-partition

We have a server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The installation and reinstallation of the last kernel package fails, because the system says 'no space left on /boot'. Though there is plenty of space.

```
root@server1:~# lsblk -o  NAME,FSTYPE,UUID,RO,RM,SIZE,STATE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME                              FSTYPE      UUID                                   RO RM   SIZE STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                   0  0 136,7G running
├─sda1                            ext2        44c5a124-edc0-4e3f-be03-d3e5a8cd2cc7    0  0   244M         /boot
├─sda2                                                                                0  0     1K
└─sda5                            LVM2_member Mynsp3-K25i-ZDba-qhO3-4SxW-Z4Op-RFyyYP  0  0 136,5G
  ├─server1--vg-root (dm-0)   ext4        cbc2363b-60a2-4f86-ab50-bab0d8d997b0    0  0 120,5G running /
  └─server1--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) swap        7e96c9b4-992a-49e5-89cb-7379d8b888b5    0  0    16G running [SWAP]
```

.

```
root@server1:~# df -h /boot
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda1       237M     54M  171M   24% /boot
```

.

```
root@server1:~# ls -l /boot
insgesamt 43579
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1169204 Aug 20 20:15 abi-3.13.0-157-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1169204 Aug 24 21:01 abi-3.13.0-158-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   166094 Aug 20 20:15 config-3.13.0-157-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   166094 Aug 24 21:01 config-3.13.0-158-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Sep 19 09:50 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22598579 Aug 24 06:33 initrd.img-3.13.0-157-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Jan  6  2015 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   176500 Mär 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178176 Mär 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   178680 Mär 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      254 Aug 20 20:15 retpoline-3.13.0-157-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      254 Aug 24 21:01 retpoline-3.13.0-158-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3416014 Aug 20 20:15 System.map-3.13.0-157-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3416014 Aug 24 21:01 System.map-3.13.0-158-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5892240 Aug 20 20:15 vmlinuz-3.13.0-157-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  5892368 Aug 24 21:01 vmlinuz-3.13.0-158-generic
```

.

```
root@server1:~# apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0-158-generic
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 erneut installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 15,6 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 307225 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../linux-image-3.13.0-158-generic_3.13.0-158.208_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/amd64-microcode 3.13.0-158-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-158-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 3.13.0-158-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-158-generic
Done.
Entpacken von linux-image-3.13.0-158-generic (3.13.0-158.208) über (3.13.0-158.208) ...
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-158-generic_3.13.0-158.208_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 Extrahierte Daten für »./boot/retpoline-3.13.0-158-generic« können nicht nach »/boot/retpoline-3.13.0-158-generic.dpkg-new« kopiert werden: Es konnte nicht geschrieben werden (Auf dem Gerät ist kein Speicherplatz mehr verfügbar)
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da die Fehlermeldung auf einen Fehler wegen voller Festplatte hindeutet.
                                                                                                               dpkg-deb: Fehler: Unterprozess einfügen wurde durch Signal (Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)) getötet
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-158-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-158-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-158-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-158-generic
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-158-generic_3.13.0-158.208_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In syslog i can see some errors for the device /dev/sda1:

```
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.720753] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 10: block 84733: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.723801] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 12: block 101629: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.723956] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 12: block 101629: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.726897] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 14: block 118525: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.727045] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 14: block 118525: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.729944] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 16: block 135421: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.730140] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 16: block 135421: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.732992] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 18: block 152317: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.733182] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 18: block 152317: invalid block bitmap
Sep 19 09:33:50 server1 kernel: [   37.736175] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_validate_block_bitmap:376: comm grub-editenv: bg 20: block 169213: invalid block bitmap
```

Though I can't see any problems when checking with e2fsck:

```
root@server1:~# e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda1

         312 Inodes sind in Benutzung (0.50% von 62496)
          54 nicht zusammenhängende Dateien (17.3%)
           2 nicht zusammenhängende Verzeichnisse (0.6%)
         # von Inodes mit ind/dind/tind Blöcken: 52/10/0
       62386 Blöcke werden benutzt (24.97% von 249856)
           0 ungültige Blöcke
           0 große Dateien

         297 reguläre Dateien
           6 Verzeichnisse
           0 zeichenorientierte Gerätedateien
           0 Blockgerätedateien
           0 Fifos
           0 Verknüpfungen
           0 symbolische Verknüpfungen (0 schnelle symbolische Verknüpfungen)
           0 Sockets
------------
         303 Dateien
```

Does anyone have a clue whats happening here?